# Intersections of $p$-Sylow subgroups of group of order $p^2q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^2q$ ($p$ and $q$ are distinct primes) and $P_1$ and $P_2$ be distinct
>   $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. Then if $Z(G) = \{e\}$, $P_1\cap P_2 = \{e\}$

How do I go about proving the above? Using Lagrange's theorem, I have that $|P_1\cap P_2|\in\{1,p\}$ (excluding $p^2$ as the subgroups are distinct), so it only remains to exclude $p$. But if $|P_1\cap P_2| = p$, then the intersection is a cyclic subgroup of $G$. How does this lead to a contradiction? I cannot see how.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sketch of a proof, with details missing (for you to work out): note that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are abelian and that, together, they generate $G$, so their intersection must be central.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this problem?

Comment: This is probably the easiest way. Did you manage to fill in the details?

Comment: I understand why they must be abelian, but why do they together generate G?

Comment: Think about the possibilities for the size of the group they generate.

Comment: They can't generate $G$ :s

Comment: They do generate $G$.

Comment: Observe that $|G:P_1|=q$ and $P_1 \subseteq \langle P_1, P_2 \rangle \subseteq G$

Comment: But why does this then mean that their intersection must be the center?

Comment: Since $P_1$ and $P_2$ are abelian! So an element of the intersection commutes with any product of elements of either of these two Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Comment: @Will their intersection must be IN the center. (That's what central means.)